# Moodle - Why is Course Completion Block showing incorrect info for a user on user/view.php

Tags: block, moodle

I am noticing strange behaviour with the course completion block when I click on a students name in the course completion report to view that individual user - it is showing no activities complete when the overall course completion report shows that the user has completed all activities.

If I choose a course completion report for a course I can see that a student has completed all activities for that course. When I click on the student's name I am redirected to user/view.php?id=36&course=28 and the course completion block now shows that the course is "Not Yet Started" and that no activities have been completed.

I am aware that cron needs to be run in order to update course completion status and have manually run cron a few times but the block does not update. I know this is not the problem anyway because the activity completion is correct on the course completion report and also on the course completion block which is shown on the course page.

Why does the course completion block on the user/view.php?id=##&course=## not show the correct details? should this block even be there?

can anyone help with this? I am using moodle 2.2.3

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to block_completionstatus; it is coded to show course completions for the currently logged in user:

```
 * Block for displayed logged in user's course completion status
```

Even if you place it on a user's profile page or other user-specific page, it will continue to show your own courses when you are logged in.